# Merging old table with new table with different structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have two tables which I need to 'merge'. The two tables are called `tblOld` and `tblNew`.

- `tblOld` has data from say 2012 to 2013
- `tblNew` has data from 2013 onwards and has a different structure

The dates do not overlap between the tables.

Simple example of the tables:

**Old table**

```
t_date       region    sub_region   sales      
------------------------------------------
1 Jan 2012   US        QR           2
1 Jan 2012   US        NT           3
1 Jan 2012   EU        QR           5
2 Jan 2012   US        QR           4
2 Jan 2012   US        NT           6
2 Jan 2012   EU        QR           10
...
31 Dec 2013  US        QR           8
31 Dec 2013  US        NT           9
31 Dec 2013  EU        QR           15
```

**New table**

```
t_date       region    sales
-----------------------------
1 Jan 2014   US        20    
1 Jan 2014   EU        50
2 Jan 2014   US        40
2 Jan 2014   EU        100
...
31 Dec 2014  US        80 
31 Dec 2014  EU        150
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
t_date        US QR      US NT    EU
-------------------------------------
1 Jan 2012    2          3        5
2 Jan 2012    4          6        10
...
31 Dec 2013   8          9        15
1 Jan 2014    20                  50
2 Jan 2014    40                  100
...
31 Dec 2014   80                  150
```

So I'm trying to create a query which will give me the results above although I'm not sure how to do this or if it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t_date,
SUM(CASE WHEN region='US' AND (sub_region='QR' OR sub_region IS NULL) THEN sales ELSE 0 END) 'US QR',
SUM(CASE WHEN region='US' AND sub_region='NT' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) 'US NT',
SUM(CASE WHEN region='EU' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) 'EU'
FROM (
    SELECT t_date
          ,region
          ,sub_region
          ,sales
      FROM tblOLD
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t_date
          ,region
          ,NULL
          ,sales
      FROM tblNEW
) t
GROUP BY t_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a UNION of the two tables:

```
SELECT t_date
      ,region
      ,sales
      ,sub_region
  FROM tblOLD
 UNION ALL
SELECT t_date
      ,region
      ,NULL
      ,sales
  FROM tblNEW
```